# Why does a question edit navigate to a new page but a new answer doesn't?

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

When I'm reading a post and someone edits the question, the bar with the text "1 edit has been made [...]" appears. When I click it, the question gets refreshed. But when I want to go back to the newest unanswered questions with the arrow in browser, the same page gets loaded. Only when I click the back arrow a second time I get back to the overview.

But after someone posts an answer and I click on the bar with the text "1 new answer [...]", I can navigate back to the newest unanswered questions directly with just one click on the arrow.

Is it meant to behave like this?

Comment: I've seen this too but it didn't occur to me that it might be a bug.

Comment: If it's by-design, I would certainly suggest it as a new feature.

Comment: Another bug with this reload is that the "On hold" bar disappears after a reload-by-clicking. When I see edits have been made to a question while I was reading it, I simply hit F5 as to not find myself in the past...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client-side script was calling `history.pushState`, which has been changed to a `history.replaceState` call.

The fix will be deployed with the next build (build rev `2016.5.6.4487` on MSE/MSO, `2016.5.6.3551` on sites).